# Find the probability that exactly $2$ urns remain empty, given that not every box receives a ball.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

> $10$ indistinguishable balls are placed in $5$ distinguishable urns.
> Find the probability that exactly $2$ urns remain empty, given that not every box receives a ball.

So, this is a conditional probability that can be written as $\text{P(exactly $2$ urns remain empty/at least $1$ box remains empty)} = P(A|B) = \dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

To choose the $2$ urns that remain empty we have $\displaystyle \binom{5}2$ ways and we have $\displaystyle \binom{7+3-1}{3-1}$ ways to put a ball in every other urn.

But I don't know how to calculate the above probability. Any help please? Thank you

Comment: You should clarify:  how are the balls placed in the urns?  The obvious thought would be that each ball has an equal probability of going in any of the urns, independently of all the other balls.  But that interpretation is not compatible with the Stars and Bars computation you appear to have done (though I don't understand why you wrote $7+3-1$ instead of $10-1$).  The Stars and Bars patterns are not equally probable.

Comment: In my (only slightly tongue-in-cheek) opinion, anyone who teaches probability by putting indistinguishable balls in urns should reconsider their choices in life.

Answer (score 1):

Number of ways to distribute all balls in the urns is clearly given by $5^{10}$.

Now suppose if $a_1$ balls go in the first urn, $a_2$ balls go in the second urn and so on and $a_5$ balls go in the fifth urn , we have $$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=10$$

whose number of solutions by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is given by $\displaystyle \binom{10+5-1}{5-1}=\binom{14}{4}$.

Now suppose no urns remain empty, so we force the condition $a_i \geq 1 $ for all $i$ where $1\le i \le 5$.

So if we assume $a_1=b_1+1, a_2=b_2+1$ and so on so that we have $b_i \geq 0$ for all $i$.

So we have our new equation as $$b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4+b_5=5$$

whose number of solutions by stars and bars is given by $\displaystyle \binom{5+5-1}{5-1}=\binom{9}{4}$.

So this was the number of ways of distributing the balls so that no urn remains empty, so that means the number of ways in which *atleast* one urn remains empty is $\displaystyle \binom{14}{4}-\binom{9}{4}$.

Therefore the probability that atleast one urn remains empty is $$\displaystyle \dfrac{\binom{14}{4}-\binom{9}{4}}{5^{10}}$$

For computing the probability that exactly $2$ urns remain empty, let $a_4=a_5=0$ and force $a_1,a_2,a_3 \geq 1$, so by similar reasoning we have the equation $$b_1+b_2+b_3=7$$

whose solution by stars and bars is given by $\displaystyle \binom{7+3-1}{3-1}= \binom{9}{2}$. But we could let any two $a_i's$ to be $0$, so we multiply by $\displaystyle \binom{5}{2}=10$, so it's probability becomes $$\dfrac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{9}{2}}{5^{10}}$$

So by dividing the above two probabilities, we get out final answer as $\displaystyle \dfrac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{9}{2}}{\binom{14}{4}-\binom{9}{4}}=\dfrac{72}{175}$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it would matter that the urns are labeled. I doubt that the question can be answered by just counting the number of outcomes because they do not have equal probabilities. Throwing 10 balls randomly (i.e. selecting urns with probability 1/5 for each ball, independently of where other balls end up)  into 5 urns gives the following multiplicities of the 30 different outcomes:

```
 0^0 1^0 2^5 | 4536/390625 
 0^0 1^1 2^3 3^1 | 12096/78125 
 0^0 1^2 2^1 3^2 | 12096/78125 
 0^0 1^2 2^2 3^0 4^1 | 9072/78125 
 0^0 1^3 2^0 3^1 4^1 | 4032/78125 
 0^0 1^3 2^1 3^0 4^0 5^1 | 12096/390625 
 0^0 1^4 2^0 3^0 4^0 5^0 6^1 | 1008/390625 
 0^1 1^0 2^2 3^2 | 6048/78125 
 0^1 1^0 2^3 3^0 4^1 | 3024/78125 
 0^1 1^1 2^0 3^3 | 2688/78125 
 0^1 1^1 2^1 3^1 4^1 | 12096/78125 
 0^1 1^1 2^2 3^0 4^0 5^1 | 18144/390625 
 0^1 1^2 2^0 3^0 4^2 | 1512/78125 
 0^1 1^2 2^0 3^1 4^0 5^1 | 12096/390625 
 0^1 1^2 2^1 3^0 4^0 5^0 6^1 | 6048/390625 
 0^1 1^3 2^0 3^0 4^0 5^0 6^0 7^1 | 576/390625 
 0^2 1^0 2^0 3^2 4^1 | 1008/78125 
 0^2 1^0 2^1 3^0 4^2 | 756/78125 
 0^2 1^0 2^1 3^1 4^0 5^1 | 6048/390625 
 0^2 1^0 2^2 3^0 4^0 5^0 6^1 | 1512/390625 
 0^2 1^1 2^0 3^0 4^1 5^1 | 3024/390625 
 0^2 1^1 2^0 3^1 4^0 5^0 6^1 | 2016/390625 
 0^2 1^1 2^1 3^0 4^0 5^0 6^0 7^1 | 864/390625 
 0^2 1^2 2^0 3^0 4^0 5^0 6^0 7^0 8^1 | 108/390625 
 0^3 1^0 2^0 3^0 4^0 5^2 | 504/1953125 
 0^3 1^0 2^0 3^0 4^1 5^0 6^1 | 168/390625 
 0^3 1^0 2^0 3^1 4^0 5^0 6^0 7^1 | 96/390625 
 0^3 1^0 2^1 3^0 4^0 5^0 6^0 7^0 8^1 | 36/390625 
 0^3 1^1 2^0 3^0 4^0 5^0 6^0 7^0 8^0 9^1 | 8/390625 
 0^4 1^0 2^0 3^0 4^0 5^0 6^0 7^0 8^0 9^0 10^1 | 1/1953125
```

This uses multiset notation: i^u(i) means there are u(i) urns which have i balls
.
So the probability of having exactly 2 empty urns is
1008/78125 +756/78125 +6048/390625 +1512/390625 +3024/390625 +2016/390625 +864/390625 +108/390625 = 22392/390625.
The probability of having no empty urns is
4536/390625 +12096/78125 +12096/78125 +9072/78125 +4032/78125 +12096/390625 +1008/390625 = 40824/78125.
The probability of having at least one empty urn is 1-40824/78125 = 37301/78125.
My interpretation of "given that.." is that one asks for the conditional probability in the Bayesian sense, and 22392/390625/(37301/78125) = 22392/186505 = 0.120061... is the result.